# when I build jmeter 5.6, an error occurs, what happened?

Tags: gradle, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

build jmeter 5.3 works well, error occurs when building version5.6, here is the error, what's happened?
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.equals(Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;)Z
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.equals(Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;)Z
Unable to find method 'org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.equals(Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;)Z'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt

I restart IntelliJ idea and clear cache, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

If you want to start from scratch you can kill all [Gradle daemons](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) process and delete `.gradle` folder in your home directory. Then restart the build.

If the issue will still be actual you might need to ask comrade Xi Jinping to turn off the firewall so you could compile JMeter.

The build passed in [JMeter Jenkins](https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/JMeter/job/JMeter-trunk/654/)

and it passes locally at (least for me):

[image]

More information:

- [Building JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)
- [How to write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html#howto)
- [How to Develop a JMeter Plugin: Intro & Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development)

Comment: I see, maybe I'm blocked by the firewall; thanks a lot.